# ItemsControl binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to change **Button** formating whenever the item in **ItemsControl** bool property is true. However, this formatting is not working.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Button.BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="False">
               <Setter Property="Button.BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <Image Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}" Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
               <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BrightText}" Text="{Binding Title}"
            </StackPanel>
         </Button>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I've tried to add **TargetType** of **Button** to **Style** with **Setter** property only **BorderBrush** but that didn't help either.

Comment: The Button is not the item container element, so you can not affect it by an ItemContainerStyle. Move the DataTriggers to the ButtonStyle resource.

Comment: Should this be a listbox if you're selecting?

Comment: moved to resource, helped, thank you

Comment: yes, I will use ListBox insted and override selected style, seems like a better solution